# How to delete an string from a list if it has an specific word in it

Tags: string, list, python-3.7

I'm trying to write a piece of code that helps me choose what to eat for breakfast according to how hungry I feel and how much time I got left (newbie personal project :p).

The thing is that if I'm really hungry but have little to no time, I want to delete a few options that have the word "avena" in it.

Here's the code (I'm not going to write it all down here, just the part that I have problems with):

```
ptiempo_bebi = ["Leche fría con punchao", "Leche fría con avena", "Leche 
fría con cereal", "Yogurt con cereal", "Yogurt solo"]
mtiempo_bebi = ["Té", "Agua hervida con punchao", "Leche caliente con avena", "Yogurt con avena cocida"]
bebi = [ptiempo_bebi, mtiempo_bebi]
```

So, if I input "I'm really hungry" but "Have little time", the list should be edited, deleting every string with the word "avena" in it.

I tried lots of things, but I've been 3 days stuck with this problem :(.

Tried using functions and .remove

```
def searchword(lists, word):
   for element in lists:
      for palabra in element:
         if palabra == word:
           lists = lists.remove(element)
           return lists
print(searchword(ptiempo_bebi, "avena"))
```

Tried using a similar function but with del and append

```
for element in ptiempo_bebi:
    for palabra in element:
        if palabra == "avena":
            del(element)
        else:
            ptiempoedit_bebi.append(element)
```

I even tried (understanding and) using List Comprehension

```
ptiempobebiedit = [ptiempo_bebi.remove(element) for palabra in element for element in list if palabra == "avena"]
```

And

```
ptiempo_bebi = [ elem for elem in ptiempo_bebi if elem == "avena"]
```

Sorry if my code looks horrible or if I really messed up any syntax.
I'd be really grateful to receive any answer and an explanation of why it works and in which part I messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter your list to exclude strings that contain a particular word or phrase using list comprehension. For example:

```
phrases = ['Té', 'Agua hervida con punchao', 'Leche caliente con avena', 'Yogurt con avena cocida']

filtered = [phrase for phrase in phrases if 'avena' not in phrase]
# ['Té', 'Agua hervida con punchao']
```